# The spark context has stopped and the driver is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parallel-processing, azure-databricks

I was calling multiple Databricks notebooks into one notebook and execute.
After cluster starts I am getting error as "**The spark context has stopped and the driver is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.**"

Each of my notebook will process very large data.

What could be the reason for this. And can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try running your master notebook from Databricks Jobs?

Comment: @DKNY Yes I am running my main class notebook

Comment: Great! Can you attach your notebook to on demand cluster with run job config settings? Additionally, check number of cores available per your Azure subscription when your all purpose cluster is spinned up.

Comment: Is on demand cluster means job clusters. For my all-purpose cluster having Driver type as 56GB, 16 Core. For Worker type: 14 GB, 4 Core.

Comment: Yes job cluster. For all purpose check if the number of cores available as part of azure subscription after your all purpose cluster is started.